# react native does not show imported tag

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

Why `<QRScanner/>` doesn't show on my device?
If I run the project only with the scanner, then everything works, but as soon as I transfer it to another file it breaks

[image]

**App.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
    import { QRScanner } from './src/Scanner';
    import { Navbar } from './src/Navbar'

    const instructions = Platform.select({
      ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for     dev menu',
      android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +     'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
    });

    export default class App extends Component {
      render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Navbar title='QR Scanner'/>
        <View style={styles.view}>
          <QRScanner/>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
      }
     }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    view: {
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'column',
      justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
})
```

**Scanner**

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
    import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo-barcode-scanner';


    export const QRScanner = (props) => {
        const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
        const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);

        useEffect(() => {
            (async () => {
                const { status } = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
                setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
            })();
        }, []);

        const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
            setScanned(true);
            alert(`${type} ${data}`);
        };

        const putOnServer = ({ type, data }) => {
            console.log('1')
        };

        if (hasPermission === null) {
            return <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>;
        }
        if (hasPermission === false) {
            return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
        }

        return(
            <View>
                <BarCodeScanner
                    onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
                    style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
                />

                {scanned && (
                    <Button title={'Tap to Scan Again'} onPress={ pressHandler } />
                )}
            </View>
        )
    }
```

Comment: can you share an expo code so that we can check there:>

Comment: Can you try giving the outer `<View> flex:1` ?